# How to avoid timeout and execute a stored procedure Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have an Azure cloud service which does some operations in the background. I want to execute a stored procedure for which I cannot determine the execution time. So please don't recommend to set a timeout, because sometimes it completes in micro seconds, the other run it may take longer than a minute.

All I need is to fire the stored proc execution and forget it. But it looks like I have tried several ways of doing it, and i cannot find a working solution.

I have tried the below

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("Purge_Data", connection)
              { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

connection.Open();

Task.Run(() => cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()));
```

Also the `cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();` is not triggering the stored procedure at all. I have tried this with a simple console app as well with .NET 4.6.1.

Please suggest any other, better way

Comment: "*don't recommend to set a timeout*" well how else do you think we could possibly help you then?

Comment: @DavidG we are handling loads of data, so i'm confused to set max timeout

Comment: Another issue you have here is that the `connection` object is likely to get disposed of while the task is running. You should wrap all that inside a single method and call it.

Comment: Does the task need to return anything to the application? If not, could you have it start an agent task? Then you'll get a confirmation the task has started, but the rest of it done (by the agent) in a different session.

Comment: @Larnu i don't have to return anything. How can i achieve the thing that you said

Comment: @DavidG wrapping the connection is fine. Its already wrapped in a `void` method

Comment: A `void` method doesn't fix the issue I mentioned, I think you should probably go and learn about async/await.

Comment: @DavidG i know about async/await, and i have already solved my problem using timeout to 0

Comment: Well, you clearly are missing some understanding because void will have zero effect on async, other than exceptions that you're not catching anyway. Setting the timeout to zero is a workaround for your problem, but a super dangerous one. If one of my developers submitted code with that, I would immediately reject it and tell them to find another way.

Comment: why cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery() didn't work, it should, it ignores timeout by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default timeout is 30 seconds so you can't resolve your issue other than by changing the timeout.

If you set timeout to 0, this means "no timeout" - your stored proc will run as long as necessary.

Of course this also means that your stored proc will literally run forever if it has a design flaw / infinite loop.

You could deal with that a couple of ways. Monitor running processes and alert you if it runs away from you, or set an improbably high but not infinite timeout (you mentioned "microseconds or more than a minute", so add an order of magnitude to that and set a timeout of a few hours).

Comment: You may want to add that the default timeout when not explicitly set is 30 seconds.

Comment: @HariHaran this is not flawless solution. Read P_J's warning. It gives your SP the ability to run forever however long it needs. Your SP may query a table that is locked by or in use by another process if its a shared SQL server. When this happens you SP will run forever without raising errors since you have no time out. This is VERY BAD. I propose you place a time out. In your code use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), when a timeout hits to retry and if it fails again then raise a log/alert and refactor your timeout